# Tour page in dark mode has a light mode gradient

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode, tour-page

When you visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page in dark mode, a gradient is visible on the question and answers section which is for light mode. The image is supposed to give a fading effect to the text while in white mode.

[image: Tour page in dark mode]
<sub>Tour page in dark mode.</sub>

[image: Tour page in light mode]
<sub>Tour page in light mode.</sub>

The gradient is also visible on the edit and commenting section.